# How to remove a file from git and all its history

Tags: git

I uploaded a file to a public repository with my password by mistake. If I would remove it now, you would still be able to find the file. How can I remove its history and all trace of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. Always consider that someone has pulled your changes and knows your password: CHANGE IT IMMEDIATELY.

Answer (score -1):

You can always delete your repository. Follow these steps:
1.On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

2.Repository settings buttonIn the repository's right sidebar, click  Settings.

3.Repository deletion buttonUnder Danger Zone, click Delete this repository.

for additional help goto https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/